# Alias one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have a `User` object and that user object can have various `Answer`s objects tied to it.

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
u=User.objects.get(pk=...)
u.answers()
```

This is the current way I am doing it -- via a `@property`, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner or more 'built-in' way to do this:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey('User')
    tag         = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    upvotes     = models.IntegerField()

class User(models.Model):
    email       = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `related_name` on the FK definition. cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

you'll do something like:

```
u.answers.all()
```